# Move fixed size line with fixed angle by mouse in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I create something like billiards cue and need to move my cue with fixed size and fixed angle by mouse.

Firstly we aim our cue to ball, then we click and save position of cue, then we need to move our line closer or farther to our ball.

https://jsfiddle.net/6qa87mw3/ here's the demo of script without `moveCue()` function. `cueCoords` object has 4 coordinates: start coordinates of our cue and end.

I need to calculate `cueCoords` from mouse position.

Comment: Here's a previous Stackoverflow [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22498201/create-vectors-and-collisions-using-kinetic-js/22525976#22525976) that shows how to aim a cue-stick at a ball and move the ball according to the cue-stick angle.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to move fixed size line closer or father to our ball and this will have maximum value.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding, but that's what the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/B6K9z/) does: Drag a fixed length cue that's always pointed at the ball. (?).

Comment: I want to move my cue (line) closer or father to ball with known angle and size, but not move cue in all area.

Comment: I don't understand, but you can calculate the cue position from the mouse position by looking at the `controller.reposition` function in the demo. Good luck with your project!